# What is the order of execution of middlewares?

Tags: express, middleware

I have two routes. First route inside global variable `route`. In start middleware, second route returns into that global variable also.

```
var route = require('./routes/first');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    route = require('./routes/second');
    next();
});
```

And when executed next middlawe I still have the first route. **Why did my first middlawe does not start before?**

```
// route contain module from './routes/first'
app.use('/api', route);
```

---

But, if I use different design of callback, it is possible to get a second route...

```
// route contain module from './routes/second'
app.use('/api', function (req, res, next) {
    return route(req, res, next);
});
```

---

**./routes/first.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var route = express.Router();

route.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('First route');
});

module.exports = route;
```

**./routes/second.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var route = express.Router();

route.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Second route');
});

module.exports = route;
```

Comment: Can you put console log before this line `route = require('./routes/second');` ?

Comment: I have written an article on importance of middleware order in Express application. Here is the link to the article:https://www.nodexplained.com/blog-detail/2018/01/11/importance-of-middleware-order-in-expressjs-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it forms a closure when it calls `app.use('/api', route);` . The route inside the `use` function does not change when you change it in the parent function. Try this

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    route = require('./routes/second');
    app.use('/api', route);
    next();
});
```

Comment: I add the `console.log()` inside the route files and inside the first middleware. The first middleware is really run at first. And I realized first middleware can't change variable inside the `app.use()`, because that the specified variable is used before start `app.listen()`, it's transformed to static route, and it's unchangeable in the process.

Comment: Yeah. It took me sometime to realise about the closure stuff and variable scope.